# Display spinner in specific component only

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, lightning-design-system

I added lightning component to the page layout but when I fire spinner it displays for all components:

[image: spinner issue]
Also I have two components with aura:id to use component.find() in doInit function. That is the reason why I can't create container div (.find() doesn't work in this case). What is the best way to display spinner in my component only?

Comment: Have you tried simply placing the spinner in a relative positioned element? You can use the `slds-is-relative` class to achieve this. If the spinner's parent has relative positioning the shade will be confined to that element.

Comment: Yes, but I want to add shade background to all my items.

Comment: I am totally confused about what you are looking for then. Could you maybe provide a quick mock-up of what you expect your component to look like?

Comment: Sure. Btw you can check my original screenshot. I want to show spinner+background inside my component only. Also I have two divs for two components that I can show/hide using specific CSS class. I tried to create container div and add relative css class but in this way I can't get id using component.find('my_aura_id').

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it with some CSS changes and change use unique aura:id for both
Do something like this ..

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="isLoading" type="Boolean" default="true" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoading}">
   <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-1">
      <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-1 isActivityLoading">
        <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="small"/>
      </div>   
   </div>
   <aura:set attribute="else">
      //Else show other data     
   </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

**CSS**

```
.THIS .isActivityLoading .slds-spinner_container {
   position: relative !important;
   top: 20px !important;
}
```

**Controller**

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    //Getting Data
    var action = component.get("c.yourAction");
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
           component.set("{!v.isLoading}", false);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

},
```

Comment: Hi Tariq! In this case you want to hide all data from the layout and display spinner. I want to display spinner+background as the layer above my layout.

Comment: @EugeneVabishchevich Try to adjust CSS for background.

Comment: @Tariq I'm not sure this `component.set("{!v.isLoading}", false);` will work.. You probably need to change it to `component.set("v.isLoading", false);`

Comment: @YonatanGoriachnick In March 2017 it was working for me. I don't know it work or not for now. as i am moving salesforce to blockchain :D